# If $\Sigma \Cup ${$\phi$}$ \vdash \theta$ and $\Sigma \Cup ${$\lnot\phi$}$ \vdash \theta$ then $\Sigma \vdash \theta.$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$\Sigma$ is a set of sentences, the set $\mathcal{L}$  consists of all axioms of the forms:

A1)
 $\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi)$

A2) $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta)) \rightarrow ((\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \theta))$

A3) $((\lnot \phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (( \lnot \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow \phi))$

*I can only use $\rightarrow$ with modus ponens.

I need to prove this and I would like some hints. I can get by Deduction theorem, $\Sigma \vdash \phi \rightarrow \theta$ and $\Sigma \vdash \lnot\phi \rightarrow \theta$. I think you need to use A3 with $\phi$ as $\theta$, but I'm not quite sure what else.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I messed up all the formatting give me a second please. edit: ok should be all good

Comment: Can't you do it by mimicking the proof of deduction theorem?

Comment: We did the proof of D.T with induction in class. I'm not quite sure how I would work with that.

Comment: See your [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924963/prove-sigma-vdash-lnot-phi-rightarrow-psi-iff-sigma-vdash-phi-and) : you need the same preliminary work, and also *contraposition* : B6) $\vdash (\phi \to \psi) \to (\lnot \psi \to \lnot \phi)$.

Comment: Thus, by*DT* we have $\Sigma \vdash (\phi \to \theta)$ and $\Sigma \vdash (\lnot \phi \to \theta)$.

Comment: By *contraposition* : $\Sigma \vdash (\lnot \theta \to \lnot \phi)$ and $\Sigma \vdash (\lnot \theta \to \lnot \lnot \phi)$.

Comment: Finally, use a suitable instance of A3).

Answer (score 0):

For deduction theorem $\Sigma \vdash \phi \rightarrow \theta$ and $\Sigma \vdash \neg \phi \rightarrow \theta$, then $\Sigma \vdash \phi \wedge \neg \phi \rightarrow \theta$, but $\Sigma \not\vdash \phi \wedge \neg \phi$.

Comment: Oh shoot. I forgot to add I can only use $\rightarrow$ and modus ponens.

Comment: Don't forget that $\phi \rightarrow \theta$ is equivalent to $\neg \phi \vee \theta$.

Comment: Does $\Sigma \vdash \phi \wedge \neg \phi \rightarrow \theta$ mean $\Sigma \vdash$ both $\phi$ and $\neg \phi \rightarrow \theta$. If so how did you get $\Sigma \vdash \phi$